# actionscript 3 function cannot access manual movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript, movieclip

I'm new to actionscript 3.0. I had the following code:

```
num0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, num0_click);
function num0_click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(num0);
}
```

With `num0` is a manually added movieclip on the stage and not a member of any other movieclip.
I had the output is `null`.
Would you please explain the situation and teach me how to access `num0` inside a function like that.

**EDIT**

The weird thing is that the function works fine if not used as a event listener:

```
trace(num0);

num0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, num0_click);
function num0_click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(num0);
}

num0_click(null);
```

the output as following

```
[object ...]
[object ...]
```

and when the movie clip instance `num0` is clicked (on the swf):

`null`

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply,

`event.currentTarget` gives you the object that is currently processing / handling that event.

Since your event handler `num0_click` is attached to `num0`, `event.currentTarget` will return what you require.

**EDIT**

A reference to `num0` is not stored anywhere (from the code you have given). If you want to access `num0` by that name again later, you must declare a variable like so, in the Class scope (or if you aren't using classes, then outside all functions).

```
var num0:MovieClip;
```

then, you can instantiate it and refer to it in any function like this:

```
function init():void {
    num0=new MovieClip();
}

function stop():void {
    num0.stop();
}
```

**EDIT 2**
You can also declare the listener function in-line in the addEventListener.

```
num0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(num0);
});
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not working.
`event.currentTarget.stop()` does not make `num0` stop.
Could you please explain to me how does `num0` become `null`? And is there any way to directly access `num0` through some kind of "canonical name"?

Comment: Edited another time. Try out EDIT2

Comment: I also edited my question. Unfortunately, your EDIT2 didn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't come back since then.
My work around is to put the accessing to num0 into a "normal" function and then call it within the event handler.